# Apply conditional formatting to one cell based on part of a text in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet containing a bank statement. In `C` I have a description of what the transaction is for sometimes just a word and other a sentence. In `D` I have money coming into the account and `E` I have money going out. What I need to do is format `D` so that if `D` has a value greater than 1000 and `C` contains a specific word then `D` changes to yellow.

I have already managed to do this for a couple conditions and they have worked such as `=AND($D2>1000,$C2="SBC")` but when I try to apply it to a cell that contains more than one word, the word I need referring to is constant, it won't work.

For example the cell containing the text said `london, m6gt 2758463027 l`, the text I would need to refer to would be `london` as the text following it is different.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH` functions together to find text within a string.

Change your formula to the following to search for "SBC" within the text contained in cell `C2`.

```
=AND($D2>=1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SBC",$C2)))
```

If the search finds it and `D2` is greater than $1,000.00, the `AND` statement will be true and the conditional format will be applied.

[source](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Check-if-a-cell-contains-text-case-insensitive-7bb505c7-2815-4a7a-9544-57a5f0dcd551?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN)